# lxml is not reading the XML opening and closing tags when they are in different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I am using lxml package to read the tags and attribute values from XML. It does read the values when opening and closing tags are in one line but it doesn't read when opening and closing tags are in different lines.
In below XML, price tags i.e.  `<price>` and `</price>` in a same line and price coming in output

a.xml

```
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <cool_number>QWZ5671</cool_number>
         <price></price>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Output:

```
[{'gender': ["Men's"], 'cool_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'price': ['None']}]
```

But if price tags  and  in different line then price is not coming in the output

a.xml

```
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <cool_number>QWZ5671</cool_number>
         <price>
         </price>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Output:

```
[{'gender': ["Men's"], 'cool_number': ['QWZ5671']}]
```

Code is the same for both xmls:

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

root_1 = etree.parse('a.xml').getroot()
d1= []

for node in root_1.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
        # iterate over the items
        for k, v in x.attrib.items():
            item[k].append(v)
        if x.attrib is None:
          item[x.attrib].append('None')
        if x.text is None:
          item[x.tag].append('None')
        elif x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())

    d1.append(dict(item))
print(d1)
```

Any idea when tags  and  in different line then why price tag is not coming in the output?
what is the solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

your issue is with this condition:

```
if x.text is None:
  item[x.tag].append('None')
```

you are checking whether the tag contains *no text at all*. this is the case here `<price></price>` because the closing tag follows the opening tag immediately. here however

```
...
     <price>
     </price>
...
```

your tag *does* contain text: a newline and some whitespace characters. to fix this you have to change your condition from `if x.text is None:` to something like `if not x.text or not x.text.strip():`